# Using jQuery to hide a div by id doesn't work in Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

In [this *Newyorker* webpage](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2014/11/24/good-game?intcid=mod-yml), the top border (Displaying "The Newyorker") takes significant amount of space.
I opened the webpage in "developer Firefox edition" and using the webpage inspector found that the div id of the border is `mobile-nav-container`.

So, why doesn't the following code work? :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        newyorker
// @namespace   N
// @include     http://www.newyorker.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==
console.log('Grease monkey start');
$('#mobile-nav-container').hide();
console.log('Grease monkey end');
```

Comment: On your side, mobile nav cointainer is hidden...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like they're using the $ function for something else. Try:

```
jQuery('#mobile-nav-container').hide();
```

Comment: Wow. Works like charm. How did you find out?

Comment: Just enter "$" in your console. If a function is returned, it's almost always jQuery. If it returns "undefined", and you know jQuery is loaded (saw it in the source), you have to use "jQuery".